# Call method stored in variable without specifying this

Tags: javascript, function, methods, this, method-call

Consider the following code.

```
class Foo {
  num = 0;
  bar = function(arg) {
    console.log(this.num + arg);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const bar = foo.bar;

foo.bar(1);

bar(2);

bar.call(foo, 3);
```

`foo.bar(1);` logs `1`.

`bar(2);` throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'num' of undefined`.

`bar.call(foo, 3);` logs `3`.

Is there a way to store the function `foo.bar` in a variable in such a way that it can be called without specifying the `this` object?

I know that the following would work.

```
const foobar = function(arg) {
  foo.bar(arg);
}
```

Is there a way to avoid creating the intermediary function? I want to pass methods as arguments to another function, and having to create lots of intermediary functions would really reduce code readability.

Comment: MDN: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Why not specify the `this` with `bind`? It's the cleanest way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the field with an arrow function; that will let `this` refer to the instance:

```
bar = (arg) => {
  console.log(this.num + arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is! You can use `.bind()`. Here's an example:

```
class Foo {
  num = 0;
  bar = function(arg) {
    console.log(this.num + arg);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const bar = foo.bar.bind(foo);

bar(2);
```